# How to enlarge the tty window in Ubuntu server 14 under vmware player?

Tags: display, screen, tty, virtual-terminal

I'm running a headless server under vmware and the tty window is too small, maybe 800x600.

I have installed the vmware tools, but the tools seems to have bugs, so the full screen mode seems buggy too.

*How can I make the tty larger?*

Comment: @Fabby what's a headless server? i'm just using a normal installation in my pc. the vmware player's window is too small. I have to use the ssh in my pc to login the ubuntu server to get a larger screen.

Comment: technical term for no x-server installed...  **;-)** so the real techies will answer your Question (and apparently someone *just* did...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

likely what you need to do is this:

1. logout of the graphical session
2. then press ctrl+alt+F1
3. login to TTY

type:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

edit to your resolution:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

type:

ctrl+o to save
ctrl+x to exit

then update grub and reboot

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Comment: It did not work for me! :( I'm using VMWare.